# Does $\int \dfrac {p(x)}{q(x)} dx$ for any polynomials $p$ and $q$ have a closed form in elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a Calculus 2 background, so please don't get too technical. If the answer is no, what are the loosest restrictions we can place on $p$ and $q$ so that the answer is yes?

Comment: Yes using the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Yes, assuming that you can factorize $q$. In general, if the degree of $q$ is at least $5$, it may not be possible to express the zeros of $q$ in terms of elementary functions, but this is a problem with the *algebra*, not the actual integration.

Comment: I find it useful, too, to emphasize that even the partial fraction decomposition is just algebra (rewriting a rational function in a different form), not calculus. It's done because it makes the calculus (almost) trivial in the new form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. See, for example, [here](http://people.clarkson.edu/~sfulton/ma132/parfrac.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps you should move some of the content into your answer, as link only answers are low quality.